# How do I set up that each time the *addMoreCredits* - Button is pressed it will subtract 1 from the *usersCredits*

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I set up that each time the *addMoreCredits* - Button is pressed it will subtract 1 from the *usersCredits* and add 1 to *amountOfCreditInGame* and I want to set up the *progressBar* to show each time any user clicks the *addMoreCredits* - Button and I tried to set the progress bar from 1 - 1000 but it didn't work - and I want to set it up that once the *progressBar* reaches 1000 the *mainImage* will change

Thanks

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainImage: UIImageView!



@IBOutlet weak var amountOfCreditInGame: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var usersCredits: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!

var usersCredit = 0 {
    didSet{
        usersCredits.text = "Credit: \(credit)"
    }}

    var creditInGame = 0 {
    didSet{
        amountOfCreditInGame.text = "Credits in: \(creditInGame)"
        }}


var gameProgress: Float = 1000.0



var credit = 0 {
    didSet {
        creditLabel.text = "Credit: \(credit)"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.gameProgress = 0
    self.progressBar.progress = 0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


@IBAction func addMoreCredits(_ sender: Any) {
    creditInGame += 1 + credit

    self.gameProgress += 1



    if self.gameProgress == 1 {
        self.progressBar.progress = 1000.0
        return
    }
    self.progressBar.progress = gameProgress

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to set the progress of the progress bar, what you should do is divide the gameProgress by 1000, so 1 / 1000. What this will do is return a fraction that can be applied to the progress bar, due to the fact that the progress bar has a minimum value of 0.0 and a maximum value of 1.0